# T-SQL calculate the first monday of the first ISO week in a year and enumerate all weeks as from-to periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, iso8601

I would like to calculate first day (Monday) in a first ISO 8601 week in a given year and subsequently enumerate all ISO 8601 weeks in the given year including their numbers. I wonder if this can be done better than I have done so far, perhaps using built in function datepart(iso_week, getdate())? Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @y as int = 2011

DECLARE @firstDayOfYear date = CAST(CAST(@y AS varchar(4)) + '-01-01' AS DATE)
--thursday before 1st Jan
DECLARE @Thursday date = DATEADD(day,
               3 - (DATEPART(dw, @firstDayOfYear) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
               @firstDayOfYear) 
DECLARE @FirstDayOfIsoWeek date = DATEADD(day,
               - (DATEPART(dw, @firstDayOfYear) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
               @firstDayOfYear)
if (@Thursday<@firstDayOfYear)
    SELECT @FirstDayOfIsoWeek  = DATEADD(d,7, @FirstDayOfIsoWeek) 

SELECT @FirstDayOfIsoWeek
```

I am also looking for a way to enumerate all the ISO weeks starting from the first monday as a table of periods with columns StartDate, EndDate, Year, Month, ISOWeekNo. If somebody knows quick and clean solution, please help.

### Accepted solution:

I have made few edits so it works as I need - to enumerate weeks in a year in the Outlook Calendar fashion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FGetISOWeeks](@y int)
RETURNS 
@ISOWeeks TABLE (StartDate Date NOT NULL, EndDate Date NOT NULL, YearNo int not null, MonthNo int not null, WeekNo int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @weeknumbers as TABLE ( weeknum int not null primary key (weeknum)) -- helper table of week numbers
    declare @weeknum int = 1
    while (@weeknum <= 53)
    begin
      insert @weeknumbers values(@weeknum)
      set @weeknum = @weeknum + 1
    end
    DECLARE @firstDayOfYear date = CAST(CAST(@y AS varchar(4)) + '-01-01' AS DATE)  
    DECLARE @Thursday date = DATEADD(day,3 - (DATEPART(dw, @firstDayOfYear) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,@firstDayOfYear)  --thursday before 1st Jan
    DECLARE @FirstDayOfIsoWeek date = DATEADD(day, - (DATEPART(dw, @firstDayOfYear) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, @firstDayOfYear)
    if (@Thursday<@firstDayOfYear) SELECT @FirstDayOfIsoWeek  = DATEADD(d,7, @FirstDayOfIsoWeek) -- calculate first day of iso year
    declare @Monday0 date = DATEADD(d,-7, @FirstDayOfIsoWeek)
    INSERT INTO @ISOWeeks
    select DATEADD(WEEK, N.weeknum, @Monday0) as StartDate
          ,DATEADD(day, 7*N.weeknum+6, @Monday0) as EndDate, @y as YearNo
          ,DATEPART(month,  DATEADD(DAY, 7*N.weeknum+3, @Monday0)) as MonthNo
          ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,  DATEADD(WEEK, N.weeknum, @Monday0)) as WeekNo    
    from @weeknumbers N
    where DATEPART(year,  DATEADD(day, 7*N.weeknum+3, @Monday0)) = @y
    order by N.weeknum  
    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a table with values 1 to 53

```
create table weeknumbers
(
  weeknum int not null
  primary key (weeknum)
)

declare @weeknum int
set @weeknum = 1

while (@weeknum <= 53)
begin
  insert weeknumbers values(@weeknum)
  set @weeknum = @weeknum + 1
end
```

Then this stored proc should give you the correct results

```
create isoweeks(@y int) as
begin

DECLARE @firstDayOfYear date = CAST(CAST(@y AS varchar(4)) + '-01-01' AS DATE)
--thursday before 1st Jan
DECLARE @Thursday date = DATEADD(day,
               3 - (DATEPART(dw, @firstDayOfYear) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
               @firstDayOfYear) 
DECLARE @FirstDayOfIsoWeek date = DATEADD(day,
               - (DATEPART(dw, @firstDayOfYear) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
               @firstDayOfYear)
if (@Thursday<@firstDayOfYear)
    SELECT @FirstDayOfIsoWeek  = DATEADD(d,7, @FirstDayOfIsoWeek)

declare @Monday0 date = DATEADD(d,-7, @FirstDayOfIsoWeek)

-- SELECT @FirstDayOfIsoWeek

select DATEADD(WEEK, N.weeknum, @Monday0) as StartDate
, DATEADD(day, 7*N.weeknum+6, @Monday0) as EndDate
, DATEADD(day, 7*N.weeknum+6, @Monday0) as EndDate
, @y as Year
,   DATEPART(month,  DATEADD(WEEK, N.weeknum, @Monday0)) as Month
,   DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,  DATEADD(WEEK, N.weeknum, @Monday0)) as Month
from dbo.weeknumbers N
where DATEPART(year,  DATEADD(WEEK, N.weeknum, @Monday0)) = @y
order by N.weeknum

end
```

Don't know whether this solution is better than the other posted. Maybe faster or slower, easier to understand or not. I guess that depends on your preference. I used your existing code as the beginning of the stored proc, but you should tweak the code to simplify calculation of Monday0 (the last monday of the prior ISO year)

Comment: There is only little problem with the WHERE condition, should be:
where DATEPART(year,  DATEADD(day, 7*N.weeknum+3, @Monday0)) = @y, to reflect Thursday. would you mind to edit it in your answer? Thank you, it is working this way.

Comment: Also you have EndDate specified twice in the output. When implementing your answer in my solution I changed weeknumbers table to @weeknumbers table variable. Despite this little edits it saved me some work, thank you.

Comment: Please feel free to edit. Sorry about the minor issues. Also should have mentioned. Having a numbers table is often useful for other things. I.e., just add where num <= 53 to the where clause if your numbers table had 10K rows.

Comment: I found one more problem: the number of month is not the number of ISO month - i.e. 2013-12-30 ... 2014-01-05 should be month 1 of 2014, not 12.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean by ISO week I think the below code should work for you.

The first part does look rather ugly, but it executes quickly. The objective is to find the first Day of the week of the first week of the year. If that's not a Monday, then that first day will be in the previous year and we want to go to the next week.

From there the recursive CTE makes short work of the second part of the problem.

```
DECLARE 
    @year CHAR(4) = 1972,
    @YearDate DATE

SELECT
     DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@year + '-01-01'),0)),0)
    ,DATEADD(WEEK,1 + DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@year + '-01-01'),0)),0)

IF(DATENAME(YEAR,DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@year + '-01-01'),0)),0)) = @year)
BEGIN
SELECT @YearDate = DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@year + '-01-01'),0)),0)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @YearDate = DATEADD(WEEK,1 + DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@year + '-01-01'),0)),0)
END

;WITH DateCTE (StartDate, EndDate, YearNum, MnthName, WeekNumber) AS (
    SELECT
         @YearDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY,7,@YearDate)
        ,DATENAME(YEAR,@YearDate)
        ,DATENAME(MONTH,@YearDate)
        ,DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,@YearDate)-1,0),@YearDate)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         EndDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY,7,EndDate)
        ,DATENAME(YEAR,EndDate)
        ,DATENAME(MONTH,EndDate)
        ,DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,@YearDate)-1,0),EndDate)
    FROM DateCTE
    WHERE DATENAME(YEAR,EndDate) = @year
)
SELECT
*
FROM DateCTE
```

Comment: Thank you, looks promising, but still has serious flaws. In 2014 the 1st ISO week starts 2013-12-30. Your 1st week starts 2014-01-06. And the 52nd week in your output is in fact 1st ISO week of 2015. You can easily check: SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2014-12-29')

Comment: I can see you're right and I think that's the part I wasn't sure about how you wanted it to function. To fix just use the first statement in the IF block without bothering to check it with an IF statement. That first statement returns the correct  2013-12-30 date you are looking for as demonstrated by the first part of the select statement above the IF.

Comment: I have tried it already and it is not working for all years. It is important to check whether current week's Thursday lies within the selected year, I think.